# Django and media files on different hosting

Tags: python, django

I have bought hostgator shared hosting, and I wanted to install django python 2.7. but they do not support python 2.7 on shared hosting. So I want to ask can I install my Django application on DigitalOcean and host my media files on Hostgator. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it's probably not worth the effort. If you are asking about media files (uploaded by the user) instead of static files (e.g. images/css/javascript) then it will be even trickier.

Comment: Should very much be possible. We host our static/media files on AWS s3. There is a django extension that provides the support for s3 in particular. Similar configuration can be achieved in your case. If your app generates new media files (for example accepting user-uploaded files) The trick will be setting up the logic to upload to the remote media file source... and you'll probably want that to be configurable to accommodate local development. Is just using digital ocean for everything not an option?